# TestNG @AfterMethod for a specific group is running after each method in Eclipse

Tags: java, testng

I don't get how the grouping works in TestNG, I have this code :

```
    @AfterMethod(groups = { "refreshPage" })
    public void refresh() throws IOException {
        driver.navigate().refresh();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {

    }

    @Test(groups = { "refreshPage" })
    public void test2() {

    }
```

And the @AfterMethod is run after both of them, even if only the second one is part of that group. I guess it doesn't relate to the Template testng.xml configuration file that is generated by eclipse for the execution. It's just a barebone setting for either the entire test class or individual test method. So it shouldn't influence groupings

EDITED:

So that in order to have @AfterMethod run after some methods only and run the entire test class, I have to run it twice, having two groups of methods (with/without refreshing).

```
<test name="Test1">
  <groups>
    <run>
      <include name="refreshPage*"/>
    </run>
  </groups>

  <classes>
    <class name="example.Test"/>
  </classes>
</test>

<test name="Test2">
  <groups>
    <run>
      <include name="dontRefreshPage*"/>
    </run>
  </groups>

  <classes>
    <class name="example.Test"/>
  </classes>
</test>
```

I have no idea how to make it work when started via Eclipse, cause the `<test>` are replaced in the Template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry but I don't understand your description of the problem. Your two test methods belong to the group "refresh", so if you run that group, you will see both of them run, and each of them will be followed by a call to prepareTest() (by the way, it seems odd that an after method would be called "prepareTest()", are you sure you don't mean for this to be a @BeforeMethod?).

There is something odd about your code, though: your two test methods declare a data provider but they don't take any argument. Either they need arguments, so you should update their signature to match what the data providers return, or they don't, and you should remove the dataProvider attribute.

Comment: Sorry for how I pasted it in there, now it's correct. I just need the "refresh()" method to be run after each method that belongs to that group. But If I run this without any further configuration, refresh() method runs after both of them, eventhough it is declared for "refreshPage" group.  test1, refresh, test2, refresh ....

Comment: So that if I run test1 via eclipse Run As... and generated template configuration, refresh afterMethod follows it, is this the expected behavior ?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the purpose of groups. Groups don't dictate what runs when, they tell TestNG which methods should be included in the test run.

Comment: I edited the question, Could you please tell me if that is correct? It seems to be convenient for finished tests, but not really for writing them.

Comment: The edited code looks good, although I'm not sure what you mean by "convenient for finished tests". To run this from Eclipse, just right click on it and select "Run as... TestNG suite" (don't forget the enclosing <suite> tags).

Comment: wow I didn't know that I could Run As those testng.xml configs, it explains everything... that's why I wrote it was convenient for finished tests...because the only way I knew to run tests was via project explorer > Run As on class/method ... I used surefire plugin for that ... thanks a lot Cedric